# xlsxwriter - Conditional formatting based on column name of the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe as below. I want to apply conditional formatting on column "Data2" using the column name. I know how to define format for a specific column but I am not sure how to define it based on column name as shown below.

So basically I want to do the same formatting on column name(because the order of column might change)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30],
                   'Data2': ["a", "b", "c"]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )
workbook  = writer.book

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
blue = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#000080', 'font_color': 'white'})
red = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#E52935', 'font_color': 'white'})

l = ['B2:B500']
for columns in l:
    worksheet.conditional_format(columns, {'type': 'text',
                                              'criteria': 'containing',
                                               'value': 'a',
                                               'format': blue})
    worksheet.conditional_format(columns, {'type': 'text',
                                              'criteria': 'containing',
                                               'value': 'b',
                                               'format': red})

writer.save()
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, it should be easy to map between column name and corresponding cell names. Please, let me know if this direction has been explored

Answer (score 2):

using **xlsxwriter** with `xl_col_to_name` we can get the column name using the index.

```
from  xlsxwriter.utility import xl_col_to_name

target_col = xl_col_to_name(df1.columns.get_loc("Data2")) 
l = [f'{target_col}2:{target_col}500']

for columns in l:
```

using **opnpyxl** with `get_column_letter` we can get the column name using the index.

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

target_col = get_column_letter(df1.columns.get_loc("Data2") + 1) # add 1 because get_column_letter index start from 1

l = [f'{target_col}2:{target_col}500']

for columns in l:
   ...
```